# Is there a way to get linkedin public profile url using email id, except third party APIs

Tags: linkedin-api, profile, public

I have tried some third party APIs for fetching the social profile URLs using email id, such as fullcontact.com, clearbit.com. But i don't want to get dependent on them. Is there any other way ? I am sure, it must be, because third parties also are fetching the profile urls using email id.